# Unable to delete registry entry: HKLM\SOFTWARE\IBM\Installation Manager\is64bit

Tags: upgrade, registrykey, ibm-rad

While installing an upgraded development environment that consists of combination of WebSphere 8.5 and Eclipse, my existing development environment (RAD & WebSphere 6) got corrupted. Looks like the 8.5 corrupted the existing regystry.

I uninstalled my old dev enviroment and am trying to reinstall it, but I get the error "Unable to delete registry entry: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\IBM\Installation Manager\is64bit`". I researched everything I could find online to resolve the problem... The one that was most promising listed on the IBM site is the one below:

> Using REGEDIT, go to the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\, look for
>   and delete any of the following folders:
>
> IBM\Client Access  IBM\Personal Communications (if PC5250 is
>   installed)  IBM\NSCMPKG (if PC5250 is installed)  IBM\Trace Facility
>   (if PC5250 is installed)  NetSoft\NS Elite (if NetSoft Router is
>   installed)
>
> Continuing in REGEDIT, go to the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\, look
>   for and delete any of the following folders:
>
> IBM\Client Access  NetSoft\NS Elite (if NetSoft Router is installed)
>
> Finally in REGEDIT, go to the keys
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\ and
>   \RunOnce. Remove any entries that reference Client Access in the data
>   field."

I couldn't find any of files suggested to be deleted...

Please advise....

Answer (score 0):

Please BACK UP YOUR REGISTRY
File > Export

change the permissions of IBM. right click on IBM. click permissions. Click on users. click remove.

I hope it will resolve the issues.

Just a user not technical person. I resolved my issue like that.

CHRISTINA ANDONOVA i hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

In software there are multiple approaches to achieve something.

As the installer is throwing "Unable to delete registry entry: HKLM\SOFTWARE\IBM\Installation Manager\is64bit", this could be the error in installer.

try installing after creating this above said entry with empty value then try with any value inside it.

give it a try.